# Display data from JSON on hover of SVG path?

Tags: javascript, css, json, svg

I am working on a SVG map of the US and I would like to display a small info window pointing to each state when you hover over it that shows the population, similar to the info windows on Google Maps. Unfortunately I'm not very good with JSON so I'm stuck at this point.

Currently I have the SVG map of the US up and the fill color changes on hover via CSS. I have a sample group of JSON data and wondering how I can incorporate it into my map so that it displays the population on hover.

Here's an example of the JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "id":"AL", 
    "population":"253045"
  },
  {
    "id":"AR",
    "population":"1529923"
  },
  {
    "id":"AZ",
    "population":"352416t"
  }
]
```

There's quite a bit of HTML due to the SVG paths, so I won't paste that here, but you can see what I have so far [on this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpg7nh5a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get info about the hovered state, first put your info in an array, so it can be accessed:

```
var info = [
  {
    "id":"AL", 
    "population":"253045"
  },
  {
    "id":"AR",
    "population":"1529923"
  },
  {
    "id":"AZ",
    "population":"352416t"
  }
]
```

Then you can get info from your array by filtering it by the `id` key using `filter`:

```
info.filter(function(state) {return state.id === currState});
```

Here is an example where you get the population of the hovered state:

```
$('path').hover(function() {
    var currState = $(this).attr('id');
    var currStateInfo = info.filter(function(x) {return x.id == currState});
    if (currInfo[0])
        console.log(currInfo[0].population);
});
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4tasLo6k/

Comment: Thank you for this, would you mind updating my JSFiddle link? I tried adding your code to my fiddle and I am getting `Cannot read property 'population' of undefined`

Comment: That's because `info` doesn't have all the states, so it can't find the correct one. I added another line that which prevents this:     `if (currInfo[0])`. I also linked to a working fiddle.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!